# Problems with list-style-image

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem with my bullet list using an image instead of regular bullets for a class assignment. The image is not placed next to the list and instead is placed in the set of words.

My HTML for this portion looks like this:

```css
     li {
       background: url('http://s30.postimg.org/52wxo16t9/bullet_Image.png') 2px 4px no-repeat;
       display: list-item;
       padding: 3px 3px 3px 20px;
       overflow: visible;
       list-style: none;
     }
```

```html
<ol>
  <li class="planet">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
  <li class="planet">Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

change it to:

```
li{
        background:url('http://s30.postimg.org/52wxo16t9/bullet_Image.png') no-repeat;
        background-size: 10px 10px;
        display: list-item;
         background-position:0px 7px;
        padding: 3px 3px 3px 20px;
        overflow: visible;
        list-style: none;
    }
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the help.

Comment: probably better to use list-style-image as the other guy answered though

Comment: I was trying to play around with the padding and make it look a specific way near the text, so yes the original list-style-image did work, but when I added in more specific code is where it stopped working.

Comment: sorry, forgot to add background-position (I edited my answer)

Comment: also note that if you do it this way, there's no point in using li/ul. you can just use divs.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that easily by using `list-style-image` property at your ol tag.

```
ol {
    list-style-image: url('your_image_url');
}
```

[**example**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_list-style-image)